# Node.js Express API with TypeScript 3 Update a record

Tags: node.js, typescript, rets

I have setup [Node.js Express API with TypeScript 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20hzY.png) and it is working fine.
I got an issue when I try to update the record.

RecordsRouter.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import {RecordComponent} from '../../components';

const router: Router = Router();
router.get('/', RecordComponent.findAll);
router.get('/:id', RecordComponent.findOne);
router.post('/', RecordComponent.create);
router.delete('/:id', RecordComponent.remove);
router.put('/:id', RecordComponent.update);

export default router;
```

My RecordComponent.ts

```
export async function update(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise <void> {
    try {
        const record: IRecord = await RecordService.put(req.body)

        res.status(201).json(record);
    } catch (error) {
        next(new HttpError(error.message.status, error.message));
    }
}
```

and my IRepository.ts

```
 export interface IRepository<T> {
    findAll(): Promise<T[]>;
    findOne(code: string): Promise<T>;
    insert(T: any): Promise<T>;
    remove(id: string): Promise<T>;
    put:(T: any)=>Promise<T>;
}
```

Service.ts

async put(data: IRecord): Promise {
try {
const validate: Joi.ValidationResult  = RecordValidation.updateRecord(data);

```
            if(validate.error) {
                throw new Error(validate.error.message);
            }

            return await RecordModel.findOneAndUpdate(data);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    },
```

Did I did all correctly or something is missing because I am getting the error
[image]

Comment: I assume that you forgot to declare `put` method in RecordService object

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Could you please share `Record/service.ts`? It is very hard to fix it without full context. You can also share github minimum reproducable repo

Answer (score 1):

That means you didn't implement all of the interface members in `RecordService`. Either implement them or mark them as optional in the `IRepository` interface by adding a question mark before the colon:

```
export interface IRepository<T> {
    findAll()?: Promise<T[]>;
    findOne(code: string)?: Promise<T>;
    insert(T: any)?: Promise<T>;
    remove(id: string)?: Promise<T>;
    put(id: string)?: Promise<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, You should implement RecordService  in next way:

```js
const RecordService:IRepository<IRecord>={
  // ...some code for findAll, findOne ....
  remove:(id: string)=>Promise.resolve(),
  put:(id: string)=>Promise.resolve(),  
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your `RecordModel.findOneAndUpdate(data)` should receive 0 arguments:

`RecordModel.findOneAndUpdate()` or `RecordModel.findOneAndUpdate(data, other, another)`

Please get familiar with [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#validating)

Comment: return await RecordModel.findOneAndUpdate(data); I am getting this error now

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Could you please provide new error in your question?

Comment: I updated the question. I do not understand RecordModel.findOneAndUpdate(data); it is comming from https://i.stack.imgur.com/20hzY.png

Comment: Or I need to create it

Comment: It is mean that you should provide either 0 or 3 argument, but not 1

Comment: What you mena by that? I am new to this. I am sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224992/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-ziaullahzia).

Comment: Thanks a lot it was great help!